# what do these tags mean: %id%, %asset%, %title%, %random%

Tags: wordpress, random

I am developing a wordpress site and have a plugin to rotate ads and the plugin says to insert these tags into the code (that pulls up the ad img source and link) where I want, but I don't know what they do. I've seen them before but can't find an answer to what they do

Answer (score 0):

They are template placeholders that will get replaced with data values i would refer to the documentation of your wordpress plugin to determine what they are for and what values you should be entering if anything , 
they are likely supposed to be entered into your template and your adrotator will replace these %% variables with their ad content data